# How can I emulate PUT/DELETE for Rails and GWT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, gwt

I would like to make my application somewhat REST compliant.  I am using Rails on the backend and [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) on the frontend.  I would like to do updates and deletes.  I realize I can do something like mydomain.com/:id/delete (GET) and accomplish the same thing.  However, as I stated previously, I would like to have a REST compliant backend.  Thus, I want to do mydomain.com/:id (DELETE) and have it implicitly call my delete method.

Now, it's my understanding that if a browser (my browser is GWT RequestBuilder) doesn't support DELETE/GET, Rails somehow accomplishes this task with a POST and some other url parameter.  So, how can I accomplish this with a GWT RequestBuilder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails does this with hidden attributes. The easiest way to figure this out would be to create a new rails application, generate a scaffold and have a look at the HTML in a browser.

Try this:

```
rails jp
cd jp
./script/generate scaffold RequestBuilder name:string
rake db:migrate
./script/server
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:3000/request_builders, click on New and have a look at the HTML. You'll see something like:

```
<form action="/request_builders" class="new_request_builder" 
  id="new_request_builder" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="e76..." />
  </div>
```

This is a creation, method is POST. Enter a name, save then Edit:

```
<form action="/request_builders/1" class="edit_request_builder" 
  id="edit_request_builder_1" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="e76..." />
  </div>
```

Of course the form is sent with POST, but Rails hads a hidden field to simulate a PUT request. Same for deletion, but the scaffold will do it with a bit of Javascript:

```
var m = document.createElement('input'); 
m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
m.setAttribute('name', '_method'); 
m.setAttribute('value', 'delete');
```

To have this work with another front-end, you'll have to both:

- Use the same style URL such as /request_builders/1 (RESTful URLs)
- Include the hidden fields (Rails trick)

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be considered a complete solution, since it works only for URL encoded data (forms), and does not work with JSON or XML, which is more common way of doing requests with GWT

Answer (score 6):

Like @skrat said, the `_method=PUT` workaround doesn't work for any kind of body where `Content-Type` is not `x-www-form-urlencoded`, e.g. XML or JSON. Luckily, there is a header workaround as well:

https://zcox.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/override-the-http-request-method-in-jersey/

So to update a REST resource, just do a POST to its address and add the header `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT`. Rails will interpret this as a PUT to the address.