# Is there any reason not to use HTTP PUT and DELETE in a web application?

Tags: http, rest, httprequest

Looking around, I can't name a single web application (not web service) that uses anything besides GET and POST requests. Is there a specific reason for this? Do some browsers (or servers) not support any other types of requests? Or is this only for historical reasons? I'd like to make use of PUT and DELETE requests to make my life a little easier on the server-side, but I'm reluctant to because no one else does.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Actually a fair amount of people use PUT and DELETE, mostly for non-browser APIs.  Some examples are the Atom Publishing Protocol and the Google Data APIs:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5023.txt
- http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html

Beyond that, you don't see PUT/DELETE in common usage because most browsers don't support PUT and DELETE through Forms.  HTML5 seems to be fixing this:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0

The way it works for browser applications is: people design RESTful applications with PUT and DELETE in mind, then "tunnel" those requests through POSTs from the browser.  For example, see this SO question on how Ruby on Rails accomplishes this using hidden fields:

- [How can I emulate PUT/DELETE for Rails and GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286321/how-can-i-emulate-put-delete-for-rails-and-gwt)

So, you wouldn't be on your own designing your application with the larger set of HTTP verbs in mind.

EDIT: By the way, if you're curious about why PUT/DELETE are missing from browser based form posts, it turns out there's no real good technical reason.  Reading around this thread on the rest-discuss mailing list, especially Roy Fielding's comments, is interesting for some context:

- http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/9620?threaded=1&var=1&l=1&p=13

EDIT: There are some comments on whether AJAX libraries support all the methods.  It does come down to the actual browser implementation of XMLHttpRequest.  I thought someone might find this link handy, which tests your browser to see how compliant the HttpRequest object is with various HTTP options.

- http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/

Unfortunately, I don't know of a reference which collects these results.

Comment: Guess what? in the latest version (19 October 2010) the PUT/DELETE support in HTML5 seems be removed. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0

Answer (score 11):

Quite simply, the [HTML 4.01 `form` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method) only allows the values "`POST`" and "`GET`" in its `method` attribute

Comment: Hmm, that would make sense... But this doesn't apply to Ajax requests, right? I can use whatever method I want?

Comment: If the browser is built to the HTML 4.01 spec, it won't understand anything other than the spec. That's all you can assume a browser can do

Comment: Browsers are usually built with more than just an HTML spec - JavaScript is not part of HTML 4.01.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden - Well, that's true. To rephrase, an HTML *document* must conform to the HTML spec. The spec allows for <script> elements and has a way for those to be tied to HTML, but it explicitly disallows any <form> method except for POST and GET.

Answer (score 4):

Some proxy servers with tough security policies might drop them. I'm using PUT and DELETE anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that some browsers do not support other HTTP methods properly, though I can't name any specifics.

Rails, in particular, will pack your forms with a method parameter to explicitly set this even if the browser doesn't support those methods. That seems like a reasonable precaution if you're going to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I say use all the features of HTTP, browsers be damned, lol.  Maybe it'll inspire more complete and proper use of the HTTP protocol moving forward.  There's more happening on the net than just POSTs and GETs.  About time browser implementations reflected this.

Comment: Haha, I wish. Unfortunately I don't think making my web application *not work* will do anything besides anger my users. :)

Comment: hmmm... yeah, i suppose you have a point.  oh well, it was a nice thought.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your browser and Ajax library.  For example [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) supports all HTTP methods even though the browser may not.  See for example the [jQuery "ajax" documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) on the "type" attribute.

The [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) Java framework lets you tunnel PUT and DELETE requests through HTML POST operations.  To do this, you just add method=put or method=delete to your URI's query string, eg:

```
http://www.example.com/user=xyz?method=delete ...
```

This is the same as Ruby on Rails' approach (as described by @ars above).

Comment: From the jQuery documentation: "Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers." So you're wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I really don't see any purpose for using PUT or DELETE in a web application. All operations that an application performs are read or write, aka input output. Why do you need to distinguish the nature of the operation in the header of the HTTP request?
I could make ajax calls with the same url of form /object/object_id
and do multiple operations like delete, update, get the value, or create.
Just by looking at the URL, I have no clue which one it is.
By using GET and POST only, my urls will be:

/object/id/delete

/object/id/create

/object/id/update

/object/id   --> implied GET

etc.

Based on my limited experience, this is a lot cleaner than hidden header request types in many cases.
I am not saying one should never use PUT or DELETE, just saying, use them only if absolutely needed.

Refer to "RESTful Web API" by Leonard Richardson to read more about different use cases and conventions regarding HTTP request methods in a RESTful web api.