# best approach to web-service/api

Tags: web-services, api

This is sort of a generalized question.

What is the best possible solution/strategy/technique/technology to create an HTTP API/web-service using PHP + MySQL, which can be called from any platform - web (html), Flash, Mobile etc. - that supports call to web services or API.

I am going to develop this API/web-service primarily for games (they will be called from games being played on any platform), so speed, scalability and security - all are highly significant factors.

How to choose from SOAP, REST, XML-RPC etc. ?

Any idea about ready-made solutions that can help fulfill my requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: I read some articles and examples on REST with PHP in last few days and I am still not able to clearly figure out why should we use REST if we can directly call URL, passing arguments (GET) or POST some data, from different platforms (flash, jquery, android etc.). Is following REST conventions faster ? securer ? more structured approach to web-service/API ?

Answer (score 2):

In this case I'd recommend a REST API. SOAP is a more complicated standard, and it makes it more difficult for those to interface to your API (for example, some PHP servers don't have SOAP enabled). As far as using PHP and MySQL to create a REST API, you can use something like [Zend Rest Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html) to make the process easy.

Comment: I agree, and I suggest to use JSON to serialize your data because there are lots of libraries for every language/technology.

Comment: thanks for the response. I read some articles and examples on REST with PHP in last few days and I am still not able to clearly figure out why should we use REST if we can directly call URL, passing arguments (GET) or POST some data, from different platforms (flash, jquery, android etc.). Is REST faster ? securer ? more structured approach to web-service/API ?

Comment: @Prashant REST is very well supported out of the box in a large number of programming languages. PHP can make REST calls using curl, Java can make REST calls with HTTP requests, Python can make rest calls with urllib, etc. A majority of the time it's part of the standard library, so it's very easy to get up and running.

Comment: @Prashant faster? It depends on what you're comparing it to. For example Flash can utilize AMF transport, which is very fast to work with compared to making an HTTP request and parsing the return. Securer? How secure it is will be up to you really. There are different authentication methods you can utilize, such as SSL encryption, token / key authentication, etc. It's only as secure as you make it.

Comment: @onteria_ Thanks for a quick response. Okay so if I go with REST architecture in developing my API (web service) in PHP, I have read in some articles that nowadays PUT and DELETE methods are not preferred to be used when their intended actions needs to be performed (add and delete resource member respectively) even if we are following REST conventions, and all data transfer to and fro is done using just POST or GET methods. Have PUT and DELETE gone obsolete in REST implementation ?

Comment: @Prashant This question asked has a nice look into the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101888/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-http-put-and-delete-in-a-web-application