# Is REST safe to implement using Javascript libraries Backbone, Zepto, and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, rest, backbone.js, zepto

I'd like to use as close to full RESTful style as a browser can manage.

Do Backbone, jQuery, and Zepto to implement the non-browser supported methods `PUT` and `DELETE` in the same way? If so, how do they implement this?

Backbone:

```
myBackbone.model.destroy() // Calls Backbone.sync('DELETE', model, options)
```

jQuery / Zepto:

```
$.ajax({ url:'/testUrl', type:'PUT' })
```

Comment: What makes you think browsers don't support PUT and DELETE? They are supported in all major browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: Things like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286321/how-can-i-emulate-put-delete-for-rails-and-gwt and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177595/why-dont-the-modern-browsers-support-put-and-delete-form-methods is this only a limitation for form methods?

Comment: Support for all HTTP methods in *HTML Forms* is not supported in older browsers.  That does not apply to JS code.  More accurately, AJAX is built on top of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest.  So if you want to read limitations (or lack thereof) go there.

Comment: Wow, how'd I miss that :)

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Did you try to run any code that failed before asking? IIRC, old browsers support PUT and DELETE via AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently REST is safe to trigger from JS, and has been for ages, just not from HTML forms.

@Matt Whipple:

> Support for all HTTP methods in HTML Forms is not supported in older
>   browsers. That does not apply to JS code.

@Benjamin Gruenbaum:

> PUT and DELETE... are supported in all major browsers.